# How do I hide spawner particles or its location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In the same world as [Are minecraft mobs ... supposed to do this?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298258/are-minecraft-mobs-supposed-to-do-this) I'm creating a lake that's teeming with crocodiles.

[image]

My "crocodiles" are actually a new 1.11 entity, `evocation_fangs`, set to spawn from those very conspicuous spawner blocks underneath green carpet. I plan to fill the lake with lily pads so the spawners blend in, but regardless, it's very easy to see where the spawners are **when those** `flame` **particles appear**.

**How do I hide those flame particles, or how do I otherwise make the spawners (mostly) inconspicuous?**

I am willing to go with practically any solution, including plugins, but resource packs are a no-can-do, and I would rather confine the spawn zone to the water if at all possible.

Comment: To the downvoter - I would love to discuss this question, clarify any part of it, edit so it's consistent with the site format - but until you tell me what you don't like you're not really helping me out here.

Answer (score 0):

### Use execute to summon at invisible entities

This is my best solution so far but it's predictable, so I'm interested in other, more natural methods.

1. Summon three groups of armor stands floating near water level:

   - Group one: `summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Group1",NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1}`
   - Group one: `summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Group2",NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1}`
   - Group one: `summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Group3",NoGravity:1b,Marker:1b,Invisible:1,Invulnerable:1,PersistenceRequired:1}`
2. Run a clock or randomizer that constantly switches between three outputs
3. Hook these commands up to each:

   - `execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=Group1] ~ ~ ~ summon evocation_fangs ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Crocodile"}`
   - `execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=Group2] ~ ~ ~ summon evocation_fangs ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Crocodile"}`
   - `execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=Group3] ~ ~ ~ summon evocation_fangs ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Crocodile"}`

This is my best option for right now but it would be simpler to just hide the spawner particles or move the spawners. All other answers still welcome.